# How do you say marketing words - lead conversion, upsell, churn reduction?

Tags: vocabulario-técnico

The customer lifecycle can be described as:

- acquisition
- lead conversion
- upsell
- cross-sell
- churn reduction (aka retention)

How would you translate these as a businessperson?

- adquisición
- conversión de candidatos (really, "candidatos"?)
- venta adicional (seems wrong)
- venta cruzada (seems wrong)
- retención (but it would be cool if there was a word for "churn")

Comment: May I suggest that you check Linguee.com, at the minimum, for each of your terms, and then come back and ask specifically about terms you still feel doubtful about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a businessperson, but here's what I found:

- Most of the [marketing articles](https://www.puromarketing.com/44/19392/ciclo-vida-cliente-parte-fundamental-plan-marketing.html) and [blogs](http://www.digitalresponse.es/blog/ciclo-de-vida-del-usuario-herramientas-email-marketing/) in Spanish, as well as other sources I checked (like Wikipedia), seem to agree in translating **acquisition as *adquisición***, **conversion as *conversión***, and **retention as *retención***. No surprise here. Just drop the "candidatos" if you don't like it (might be redundant anyways).
- **Upsell** o **up-sell**:

  - [Some sources](https://vilmanunez.com/que-es-up-selling-y-que-es-cross-selling/) translate it as "**venta adicional**". Seems to be the most used translation.
  - [Others](http://cuadernodemarketing.com/up-selling-y-cross-selling-dos-tecnicas-que-hay-que-utilizar-pero-saber-diferenciar-y-administrar/) use the term "sobreventa". This last term is already being used for *overselling*, though, so I wouldn't pick it if I had to choose.
  - [Several](https://www.palbin.com/es/blog/p210-cross-selling-y-selling-2-tecnicas-para-vender-mas-en-tu-ecommerce.html) [sources](https://eduarea.wordpress.com/2012/09/26/que-es-el-upselling-upsells-como-venderle-mas-a-sus-clientes/) just use the English term, "upsell", sometimes [even as a noun](https://blog.hotmart.com/es/que-es-upsell/).
- **Cross-sell**: near-unanimity once again, with everybody using the term "**venta cruzada**", as seen in the linked references for *upsell*. [Wikipedia uses this term too](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venta_cruzada) (you can switch languages and see how they are the same concept).
- **Churn reduction**: here "churn" is just short for "**churn rate**", which in Spanish is usually translated as "tasa de cancelación" or "**tasa de abandono**" (see [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tasa_de_cancelaci%C3%B3n_de_clientes) once again, and [some](https://www.40defiebre.com/que-es/churn/) other [sources](https://www.iebschool.com/blog/que-es-churn-rate-marketing-digital/)). So when talking about "**churn** (rate) **reduction**" you can just say "**reducción del** (o de la tasa de) **abandono**" if you want to go full Spanish, or [leave "churn" as-is](https://www.marketingdirecto.com/marketing-general/marketing/el-churn-preocupa-cada-vez-a-mas-empresas) as some do.